# Basic PHP mail field validation Implementation

Tags: php, validation, email

I have a very basic form on a throw-away site that works fine (name, email, message).

Recently, I started receiving a lot of spam messages where the name field comes through with some random combination of letters and numbers, the email comes through as some random email address and the message field is blank.  I thought it would be a good opportunity to learn some better field validation.

I started by implementing a client-side solution using the HTML5 input pattern attribute.  That works great, except as you would expect, the spambot simply bypasses the client-side validation.

The canned PHP that I'm using for the mail functionality uses a function against injections.  Since I don't know a lot of PHP, I've tried to emulate that function structure for purposes of validating the name field to only include letters and spaces (I'll go back add a couple additional characters once I get it working).

It doesn't work as it's written now.  I'm pretty sure the issue is with how I'm writing the variables at the top.  I've tried switching the if/true, else/false in my nameCleaned function to make sure I wasn't getting the logic backwards.  The function either sends the mail regardless if there are numbers in the field or kills it with the error message when the input is entered correctly... depending on which way I have it.

**The PHP**

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}

$fromName = $_POST['fromName']; 
$fromEmail = $_POST['fromEmail']; 
$customerMessage = $_POST['customerMessage'];



//Validate first
if(empty($fromName)||empty($fromEmail)) 
{
    echo "We at least need your name an email";
    exit;
}

if(nameCleaned($fromName))
{
    echo "Stop spamming me please";
    exit;   
}

if(IsInjected($fromEmail))
{
    echo "That doesn't look like a valid email address";
    exit;
}

if(nameCleaned($fromName))
{
    echo "Quit spamming us";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'ourdomain.com Web Message';//<== Email From
$email_subject = "Message from ourdomain.com";//<==  Email Subject

//Begin Email Body

$email_body = "$fromName is emailed us through the website. \n\n".

    "EMAIL ADDRESS: \n$fromEmail \n\n".

    "HERE'S WHAT THEY SAID: \n$customerMessage \n\n".       


$to = "ouremail@domain.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $fromEmail \r\n";

//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//Mail sent, redirect
header('Location: http://ourdomain.com/thank-you.html');

// nameCleaned function
function nameCleaned($str){
if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,35}/"))
        {   
        return false;
    }
    else
      {
      return true;
      }
}

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return false;
  }
  else
    {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**The Form**

```
<form method="post" action="assets/php/mailForm-validate.php">
    <div class="field half first"><input type="text" name="fromName" placeholder="Name" /></div>
    <div class="field half"><input type="email" name="fromEmail" placeholder="Email" /></div>
    <div class="field"><textarea name="customerMessage" placeholder="Message" rows="6"></textarea></div>
    <ul class="actions">
        <li><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean a simple implementation or simple to write? The simplest to write would be to just install a package from [packagist](https://packagist.org/) that deals with validation and use it. [This](https://github.com/illuminate/validation) one looks very simple to use.

Comment: Also, if your objective is to defeat bots, you might want to add a [csrf](https://packagist.org/search/?q=csrf) or a [captcha](https://packagist.org/search/?q=captcha).

Comment: The basic one is `if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ /*valid*/ }else{ /*not valid*/ }` http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: @solarc yeah.  I appreciate it. Longer term, I'll dig into some of the validation libraries/packages. I'll also add a honeypot to this form. Really just using this as a learning exercise. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @DanMiller I've seen that for the email input. Was working out the correct way to use a regular expression to filter the name input.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `nameCleaned` function.
You are useing the `preg_match()` function, but you provides only one parameter.

---

`preg_match` takes at least 2 parameters. The first is the pattern, the second is the subject. Your subject is the `$str` variable. So here is the correct code:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,35}/", $str)
```

And here is the full function:

```
function nameCleaned($str){
    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{2,35}/", $str))
    {   
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
       return true;
    }
}
```

I hope, I helped!

Comment: Okay.  I understand what you're saying with preg_match needing 2 parameters.  However, when I implement it as-is with the updated nameCleaned function, it's echoing my "That doesn't look like a valid email address" error message... not the nameCleaned error message and regardless if the name is "clean" or not.